# How to create a separate DbCompiledModel for each type of server being used

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I know this question has been asked before and I have read all of them but they did not help me :(

I am trying to create a controller with views.

I was using EF 6 and had this configuration in web.config:

```
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql" />
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
  <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, Npgsql.EntityFramework" />
</providers>
```

then I found out that EF6 does not support scaffolding so I downgraded EF to version 5. It turned out that EF 5 does not recognize  tag so I removed it:

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql" />
</entityFramework>
```

Now when I try to create a controllers I get this error:

```
Using the same DbCompiledModel to create contexts against different types of database servers is not supported. 

Instead, create a separate DbCompiledModel for each type of server being used.
```

This is my `connectionStrings`:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="MyConnection" connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=hotel;User Id=postgres;Password=6060;" providerName="Npgsql" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I know this should be trivial. Excuse the noob :(

How do I fix this?

I will post more code if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Not really a solution to the problem, but a workaround:

**Comment connection string in web.config before adding controller, then you may uncomment it**

And I've got no clue why on Earth it works this way